# What exactly is the thread context in C#?

Tags: c#, wcf, threadcontext

I have a WCF service and it logs each call to the database. Later on, if an exception occurs, it is also logged to a separate database.

I wanted a way to tie both of these logs together so we can see what might have caused the exception. To do this, I wanted some kind of unique ID that I could get for each call.

Since the whole thing is executing on a single thread, I could for example, set the thread name to a GUID eg. `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();` but this is a bit hacky.

Searching around the net, I discovered `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentContext.SetProperty()` but I am wondering exactly what that context is. Is it designed to store properties for the duration of a thread? Is it unique per thread?

If I have 5 simultaneous WCF calls I don't want there to be any conflicts between what's going in the context if it's not 'per call' so to speak.

Could someone clarify?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wouldn't use that property since Microsoft say it's for internal use only:

*`"This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code."`*

However, you should be able to use [`Thread Local Storage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243.aspx) to do the same kind of thing. That link gives an example showing how to set a string property for a thread.

Also see http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1d42da/working-with-thread-local-storagetls-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: As a update, if you are using .NET 4.6 you should switch from using `ThreadLocal` to [`AsyncLocal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn906268(v=vs.110).aspx), this allows your storage to flow across a async/await boundary where you could end up jumping threads.